# Java - Saving 10 Sudoku move into an ArrayList, then void the 2 last moves

Tags: java

I have a homework to finish but I have no idea how to handle it, my teacher whant me to use an ArrayList, but we did'n learn how to use it... So need help.

Here is all my code
Sorry for the french comment in the code.
So what my program does:

1. Say welcome
2. Ask the user to choose a level of difficulty and then print the Sudoku
3. Verify if the value in the sudoku are right or wrong and print a message
4. Here start the problem; I have to set the value of 10 board[][] (the method has to be in Class Case (the last one)
5. I also have to save these 10 value (not only the value but where I use it in the board [][]) and I have to use an ArrayList to do it
6. Cancel 2 of these step, I mean, I juste place 10 value, I have to cancel 2 of those to return to the original value board[x][y] = 0

So the probleme for me is really the ArrayList. To set a value I just did one but I can do it 10 time, unless you have an Idea, it can be random value or set value, or ask the user. In my class Case, I'm suppose to create object to save the board[x][y] = z (location on the board and the new value)

Thanks

```
import java.util.BitSet;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Scanner;

// Classe principale pour faire démarrer le logiciel. 
public class TN4 {


public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println("Bienvenue dans le sudoku de l'ecole Saint-Pruneau.");
    // Initialisation de la fonction pour Imprimer la grille
    Sudoku9x9 IGrille = new Sudoku9x9();
    String N1;
    //Declaration de la variable contenant le niveau de difficulté en appelant la methode permettant a l'utilisateur de choisir son niveau de jeu
    N1 = IGrille.Difficulte();
    IGrille.setNiveau(N1);
    N1 = IGrille.getNiveau();


    //appel de la grille originale 
    IGrille.GrilleOriginale(N1);

    //Affichage de la grille
    IGrille.Grille();
    //Validation de la grille
    boolean Vali = IGrille.validate();
    if (Vali == true){
        System.out.println("Les placement sont valide");
    }
    else {
        System.out.println("Les placements ne sont pas valide, veuillez essayer de nouveau");
    }

    //System.out.println(Vali);
    Sudoku9x9 Test = new Sudoku9x9();

    Case Placement = new Case();
    Placement.fairePlacement();
    IGrille.Grille();
}

}
class Sudoku9x9 extends Sudoku {
//Declaration du scanner pour les données a entrées par l'utilisateur
static Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

public void setBoard(int x, int y, int value) {
    board[x][y] = value;

}







//Declaration des valeur de chaque case pour la grille originale selon le niveau de difficulte choisi.
public void GrilleOriginale(String N){
    if (N == "facile"){
    System.out.println("Voici la grille initiale de niveau " + N + " : ");

    board = new int[][] 
            {{0,0,4,8,0,6,9,1,7},
            {0,0,0,1,4,9,2,0,5},
            {1,0,9,5,0,7,4,0,8},
            {4,3,6,7,9,0,0,2,1},
            {0,0,2,4,6,1,0,9,3},
            {9,1,0,2,0,3,0,4,6},
            {2,8,1,6,7,4,3,5,9},
            {7,9,5,3,1,2,6,8,4},
            {6,4,3,9,0,0,1,7,2}};
    }
    if (N == "intermediaire") {
        System.out.println("Voici la grille initiale de niveau " + N + " : ");
        board = new int[][] 
            {{0,0,4,8,0,6,9,1,0},
            {0,0,0,1,4,0,2,0,5},
            {1,0,0,5,0,7,4,0,8},
            {4,3,6,7,0,0,0,2,1},
            {0,0,2,0,6,1,0,9,3},
            {9,0,0,2,0,3,0,4,6},
            {2,8,1,6,7,4,3,5,9},
            {0,9,0,3,1,2,6,8,4},
            {6,0,3,9,0,0,1,0,2}};

    }
    if (N == "difficile") {
        System.out.println("Voici la grille initiale de niveau " + N + " : ");
        board = new int[][] 
            {{0,0,4,8,0,6,9,1,0},
            {0,0,0,1,4,0,0,0,5},
            {1,0,0,5,0,0,4,0,8},
            {4,0,6,0,0,0,0,2,1},
            {0,0,2,0,6,1,0,9,3},
            {9,0,0,0,0,3,0,4,6},
            {2,0,1,0,7,0,0,5,9},
            {0,9,0,3,1,2,0,8,4},
            {6,0,3,9,0,0,1,0,2}};           
    }
}

//Methode permettant à l'usager de choisir son niveau de difficulté et retournant celui-ci
public String Difficulte(){
    System.out.println("Veuillez choisir votre niveau de jeu:\n1 = Facile\n2 = Intermediaire\n3 = Difficile");
    int nombre = 0;
    String Niveau = "";

        nombre = sc.nextInt();
        while (nombre < 1 || nombre > 3){
            System.out.println("Vous devez choisir un nombre entre 1 et 3, essayez de nouveau:\n");
            nombre = sc.nextInt();
        }  


    if (nombre == 1){
        Niveau = "facile";
    }
    if (nombre == 2){
        Niveau = "intermediaire";
    }
    if (nombre == 3){
        Niveau = "difficile";
    }
    System.out.println("Vous avez choisi le niveau " + Niveau + ".\n");
    return Niveau;
}
}

abstract class Sudoku {
    public String Bonjour = "Variable bonjour de la methode bark";
    private String Niveau;
    static int[][] board = new int[9][9];

    //Setter pour le Niveau de jeu
    public void setNiveau(String c) {
        this.Niveau = c;
    }


    //Getter pour le niveau de jeu
    public String getNiveau() {
        return Niveau;
    }

    public abstract String Difficulte();

    // Methode Grille est concu pour afficher toutes les valeur de notre sudoku, et si "0" la case est vide et on affiche "." 
    public void Grille() {
        for (int i = 0; i < 9; i++) {
                System.out.print("\n");
                if(i%3==0)
                    System.out.print("\n");
            for (int j = 0; j < 9; j++) {
                if (j % 3 == 0)
                    System.out.print(" ");
                if (board[i][j] == 0)
                    System.out.print(". ");
                if (board[i][j] == 1)
                    System.out.print("1 ");
                if (board[i][j] == 2)
                    System.out.print("2 ");
                if (board[i][j] == 3)
                    System.out.print("3 ");
                if (board[i][j] == 4)
                    System.out.print("4 ");
                if (board[i][j] == 5)
                    System.out.print("5 ");
                if (board[i][j] == 6)
                    System.out.print("6 ");
                if (board[i][j] == 7)
                    System.out.print("7 ");
                if (board[i][j] == 8)
                    System.out.print("8 ");
                if (board[i][j] == 9)
                    System.out.print("9 ");
            }
        }
        System.out.print("\n");
    }


    //Fonction fourni par le cour pour valider les case du sudoku
    public boolean validate() {
        // un tableau : int[][] board = new int[9][9]();
        // initialisation et actions sur le Sudoku
        //int[][] board = new int[9][9];

        //Vérifie les lignes et les colonnes
        for (int i = 0; i < board.length; i++) {
        BitSet bsRow = new BitSet(9);
        BitSet bsColumn = new BitSet(9);
        for (int j = 0; j < board[i].length; j++) {
        if (board[i][j] == 0 || board[j][i] == 0) continue;
        if (bsRow.get(board[i][j] - 1) || bsColumn.get(board[j][i] - 1))
        return false;
        else {
        bsRow.set(board[i][j] - 1);
        bsColumn.set(board[j][i] - 1);
        }
        }
        }

    //Vérifie les quandrans (3x3)
    for (int rowOffset = 0; rowOffset < 9; rowOffset += 3) {
    for (int columnOffset = 0; columnOffset < 9; columnOffset += 3) {
    BitSet threeByThree = new BitSet(9);
    for (int i = rowOffset; i < rowOffset + 3; i++) {
    for (int j = columnOffset; j < columnOffset + 3; j++) {
    if (board[i][j] == 0) continue;
    if (threeByThree.get(board[i][j] - 1))
    return false;
    else
    threeByThree.set(board[i][j] - 1);
    }
    } 
    }
    }
    return true;
    } 

}

class Case {
    int Line;
    int Row;
    int Value;
    ArrayList Placement = new ArrayList();
    Sudoku9x9 Placer = new Sudoku9x9();
    public void fairePlacement() {
        Placer.setBoard(0, 0, 1);

    }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. We are glad to help you learn to program. Please show us a little of what you have tried and ask a specific question about what part is giving you trouble. Many people will be happy to explain what you need to know when you ask a detailed and precise question. Good luck!

Comment: Define "void a move." As said, we need a more specific, clear, and well-defined question.

Comment: To start, you should explain how you determine what the 10 values are that you need in step 1. Where do you get these values from?

Comment: you should tell what you've tried. Anyway this may help you. http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/66580/sudoku-solver-in-java

Answer (score 0):

1. Create a stack of `<x, y>` pairs to store the moves you make.
2. For each move you make push current move to the stack.
3. Pop the top item from the stack and set board[x][y] = 0.

Repeat step 3 every time you need to revert the last move, in your particular case you should to this twice.

You might also consider creating a custom class `Pair` to represent a place on the board.

Comment: How to I create a stack? ArrayList<x, y> ? My Class Case is supose to represent a place on the board, because I'm not suppose to use more class in this homework.